# Accessing the setters and getters methods

Tags: android, android-custom-view

I have an A activity that uses a setContentView(R.layout.activityA) method to set a layout. An activityA layout consists of a customView. My customView has a bunch of setters and getters. How can I access them from A activity? When I create an instance of customView in an acitivity A then it works but the customView is created twice: once from the setContentView and the second time when I create a new instance of it. Is there another way of accessing those method? Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried something like this in your Activity's code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle state){
    super.onCreate(state);
    setContentView(R.layout.activityA);
    CustomView customView = (CustomView)findViewById(R.id.customviewId);

    Something x = customView.someGetterMethodX();
    ...etc...

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the simple and working solution. I'm overthinking the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Java Reflection](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/reflect/package-summary.html) to read attributes and call methods.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to create it twice, simply find your custom view id and assign it to a CustomView reference. Something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.theLayout);

 CustomView customView = (CustomView) findViewById(R.id.customViewId);

customView.setSomething(someValue);

}
```